# How to close previous NSWindow each time in Cocoa.?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow, modal-window

[image]

I want that, whenever I run the application, all previous windows should be closed.
I want to display only one window at a time.

Comment: Do you mean all windows of every app or the windows of your app?

Comment: @Willeke, when my app starts only last window should be shown rest should be closed.

Comment: Is this a document-based application? You could disable window restoration for documents. I'm not sure how you're managing windows if it's not, but you could also just programmatically close the windows on app termination.

Comment: @LucasDerraugh no, it's not a document-based application.

Comment: @PankajMundra So why not close all the windows on application termination? What is meant by the last window? The last window to have key focus? The last one to be opened? I really don't see why you can't enumerate over the application's windows and close the ones you don't want to be opened if that's really what you want.